# What degree does MongoDB use for its BTree index?

Tags: mongodb, b-tree

I'm trying to **find the degree that MongoDB uses for its BTree index** (using Knuth's definition of degree). I've been looking at MongoDB's and WiredTiger's source code, but I find nothing. I stumbled upon [an article](https://zhangliyong.github.io/posts/2014/02/19/mongodb-index-internals.html) that said MongoDB uses a degree of 1024, but the article's sources point to webpages that no longer exist.